# Rails has_many, belongs_to using three tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables

- Memberships
- User_Groupings
- Users

This is how I am trying to join them.

```
User.id == Memberships.user_id
User.user_type == User_Groupings.user_type
Memberships.group_id == User_Groupings.group_id
```

I would like to do this by using associations if possible.

I have no idea how to do a belongs to or has many that is this complex.

My end goal is to be able to call user_grouping.users and get all users that match the above fields.

Answer (score 0):

visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

it will solve all your question related to associations .

Answer (score 0):

```
User.id == Memberships.user_id
```

gives:

```
class Membership
   belongs_to :user
class User
   has_many :memberships
```

but the other two are not standard Rails associations.

```
User.user_type == User_Groupings.user_type

Memberships.group_id == User_Groupings.group_id
```

You could potentially model these by passing conditions to the associations

perhaps you could update the names of these tow reflect more standard associations (or at least to give us a better idea what you want)

eg

```
User.user_grouping_id == User_Groupings.id
Memberships.user_grouping_id == User_Groupings.id
```

then if you want "user_type" you can make it a method eg:

```
class User
  def user_type
     self.user_grouping.user_type
  end
```

Comment: My end goal is to be able to call user_grouping.users and get all users that match the above fields. I can modify the user_groupings table but the others would not be easy to change.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you mean by "all users that match the above fields"? perhaps give a use-case/scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I may be not quite seeing what you are doing and therefore missing the point.

It seems you are trying to do too much with user_groupings in that it has an ID field fir user_type and group_id. My first reaction would therefore be to say that you should have user_type and group_id to either be in two different tables, or to have them as the same field (the second option seems unlikely)

You have none standard foreign keys by using belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :xxxxx_id

sorry this isn't directly answering your question, but I think you should take another look at your database design

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to have another model to associate memberships and users.
And then you associations will be like this.

```
class User
  belongs_to :user_grouping
  has_many :user_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :memberships, :through => :user_memberships
end
```

And..

```
class UserGrouping
 has_many :users, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

And..

```
class Membership
 has_many :user_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :users, :through => :user_memberships       
end
```

And..

```
class UserMembership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :membership
end
```

Of course, you have to puts respective foreign keys in tables.

Hopefully, this will help you.